# How to use EventHubsForeachWriter in Azure Databricks

Tags: spark-structured-streaming, azure-eventhub, azure-databricks

I'm trying to use EventHubsForeachWriter, as showed [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/1c198ba39a612afc08dca2646a1584570295ae1b/docs/structured-streaming-eventhubs-integration.md#foreachwriter):

```
val ehConf = EventHubsConf("YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING") 
val writer = EventHubsForeachWriter(ehConf)

val query =
  streamingSelectDF
    .writeStream
    .foreach(writer)
    .outputMode("update")
    .trigger(ProcessingTime("25 seconds"))
    .start()
```

but i'm getting an exception:

```
notebook:22: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsForeachWriter
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
    .foreach(writer)
```

Comment: same thing here for me.  hope to get it fixed and update you.  you didn't find a solution in the mean time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in this github [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/issues/414).

So, I guess the following should work:

```
val query =
  streamingSelectDF
    .select(to_json(struct("*")) as 'body)
    .selectExpr("cast(body as string)")
    .as[String]
    .writeStream
    .foreach(writer)
    .outputMode("update")
    .trigger(ProcessingTime("25 seconds"))
    .start()
```

Comment: Yeah, I was the one who posted the question there too.. :)